# How to install a custom keyboard in Android?

Tags: keyboard

I read [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5559357/) which says that I can "can install any custom keyboard as the default keyboard on Android". How can I do that? Does it require rooting?

Comment: No it doesn't require rooting.

Comment: In case somebody is interested in a command-line way, you can refer to my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133775/96277).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. I've used [Swype](http://www.swype.com/) as well as [TouchPal Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5) as alternatives.

Once you install any new keyboard, just go to Settings > Language & Keyboard to set your keyboard/text settings.

Comment: None of the links work.

Comment: Thanks. The question I linked to has been removed, so I removed the link. I fixed the link to Swype and added one to TouchPal.

Answer (score 6):

I found that even after changing the setting it didn't use the new keyboard.  I had to do a long press in a text field.  That showed an option for which input method to use.  Once selecting the new keyboard it worked all the time.

Comment: +1 I don't recall Swype requiring this, but great point!

Comment: It also allows you to switch back if you're having a tough time getting used to the new keyboard.