# How to add a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, customization

Disclaimer: There seem to be a number of potential duplicates to this question on common android forums and SX sites (e.g.: [How to install a custom keyboard in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4228/how-to-install-a-custom-keyboard-in-android)), but many are a couple of years old and none seem to be what I'm hoping for. Thence:

Looking for a solution that

- does **not** require rooting
- does **not** require additional apps, *ideally*
- does **not** require "serious" coding

Any ideas?

---

See also:

- http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/295480-custom-keyboard-layout.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326072/android-custom-keyboard-xml-file
- and [How to install a custom keyboard in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4228/how-to-install-a-custom-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: Not that it's of much relevance here, but I know of ways in both Linux and Windoze to "install" a custom keyboard layout... (*without* having to resort to 3rd-party software for it)

Comment: Which device are we talking about here?

Comment: `Samsung S4 mini`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I suggest you develop a new keyboard. You can find several code templates to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Closest working solution I was able to get was to use [JBak Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbak.JbakKeyboard&hl=en) which allows you to customise it's layout and skins using simple XML files.

Comment: Watch the permissions on that - jbak keyboard has full internet access! I don't know that it's doing anything wrong, but that seems inappropriate to me.

Comment: Maybe because it downloads dictionaries off the internet. And one can always use AppOps, if so inclined

Comment: AppOps only worked in a few versions of Android, none of which are on any of my current devices. So I don't really think that's a good solution for the average user right now.