# How to add a custom keymap / keyboard layout to Sony Xperia keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, sony-xperia, input-methods

As far as input methods go, I like the Xperia Keyboard from Sony best.

However, I would like to slightly modify the English keymap. Specifically, I want to add some additional accented characters to the list of long-press alternatives for both "e" and "a".

I don't mind whether I replace some of the existing ones (so that "e" still has five accented alternatives and "a" still has seven) or add new ones; whichever is easier.

Is there any sensible way to do this?

Xperia Keyboard supports many languages which can be downloaded from its Input Method settings, and I presume some of these have several keyboard layouts (as there is an option to choose keyboard layout for your chosen language; I'm not sure as English (UK) only has one keyboard layout (QWERTY) but this option wouldn't make sense if at least some languages didn't have multiple layout options). This suggests that there is a place somewhere on my phone where I should be able to put an input language / keyboard layout file in some format and this would be recognised as one of my keyboard options in Xperia Keyboard settings.

My concern is that this may be in some part which is only accessible by if the device is rooted. I would happily root mine but to my best knowledge there is no known method to root it currently (Sony E2303, Marshmallow 6.0.1, bootloader unlock not allowed).

Ideas?

Comment: Try the hacker keyboard maybe it is in the play store

Comment: Thanks Liam, but what I'm after is a way to edit the keymap within Xperia Keyboard, or adding a custom one.

Comment: Have you tried I'm pretty sure it allowed for custom keyboard layouts?

Comment: You can customise the keyboard to a limited extent (move smiley keys around etc) but that's not really what I'm after: I need to add custom accented characters that are not in EN_GB to that layout.

Comment: this is slightly a duplicate I am actually trying to do a similar thing http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54335/how-to-add-a-custom-keyboard-layout I assume you have tried reading the other duplicate/similar questions, but I am not sure.

Comment: I have reread your question you seem to be after the specific keyboard you are using this makes it more complicated.

Comment: Actually I've just had an epiphany and looked into the Xperia Keyboard apk. The basic character maps are in the "assets" folder, in plain text, so one can edit them there, and probably re-name and re-sign the apk just so that it does not get updated when there's a new version of Xperia Keyboard. This is hardly a solution though, more of a dirty hack. For one, this would have to be repeated every time Xperia Keyboard is updated.