# Don't have a keyboard in my phone, and cannot install a new one with ADB either

Tags: adb, keyboard

I had a keyboard in my phone (Google Keyboard), which, when I somehow installed yesterday, didn't give me the option of moving it to the SD card. Today, for some reason it gave me the option to move it to the SD card, so I did. And now I can't use it at all. This is because the "Languages and Input" sub-menu crashes when I try to enable the keyboard app too, but this has been going on since forever.

I've tried to uninstall it probably a dozen times (using both ADB commands the phone interface) and re-install it, used the following methods to forcibly install it (via ADB):

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133775/150206
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/136545/150206

but nothing. When I use the "adb shell settings put secure default_input_method "ID"" command it does nothing at all (does not even give a response in the command prompt), and when I use the "adb shell ime enable ID" command it doesn't work either (it says 'error:unknown id:null').

What do I do?

Comment: Backup your data and do a factory reset

Comment: Why would one want to move the gboard (keyboard app) to an external memory card?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was just a stupid move from my side. The `error: unknown id: null` message it was displaying, was there because I didn't put the whole mID into the `adb shell settings put secure default_input_method "ID"` command. I only put the half piece of the mID (only until the /). Anyway, now that I copied the full mID onto the command, it works again.

Comment: So you should accept your own answer.